# How to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in the express.js framework on node.js

Tags: node.js, express, cors, webserver, cross-domain

I'm trying to build a web server in node.js that will support cross-domain scripting, while still providing static files from a public directory. I'm using the express.js and am not really sure how to allow cross-domain scripting (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs), which I did not find helpful.

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function () {

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function () {


    var oneYear = 31557600000;
    //    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.listen(8888);
console.log('express running at http://localhost:%d', 8888);
```

Comment: Notice the app.all vs app.get.
It is OPTIONS request not GET

Comment: see [local-web-server](https://github.com/75lb/local-web-server) for an example of a simple node, static webserver which supports CORS

Comment: see enable-cors.org/server_apache.html for more info

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` makes your API interesting for phishing apps. Consider allowing only known origins.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Check out [the example from enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html):

> In your ExpressJS app on node.js, do the following with your routes:
>
> ```
> app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
>   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
>   next();
>  });
>
> app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
>   // Handle the get for this route
> });
>
> app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
>  // Handle the post for this route
> });
> ```

The first call (`app.all`) should be made before all the other routes in your app (or at least the ones you want to be CORS enabled).

[Edit]

If you want the headers to show up for static files as well, try this (make sure it's before the call to `use(express.static())`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

I tested this with your code, and got the headers on assets from the `public` directory:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.listen(8888);
console.log('express running at http://localhost:%d', 8888);
```

You could, of course, package the function up into a module so you can do something like

```
// cors.js

module.exports = function() {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
  };
}

// server.js

cors = require('./cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. 
I did what you suggested (first part, but still don't see any different in the request headers)
I've attached my current code above.
can you explain how I can integrate the rest of your solution to that?

Comment: I'm surprised that, since you're `use`ing `app.router` before `express.static` that it doesn't modify the headers for static files; in any case, I've updated my answer so that it works.

Comment: Thanks! I see that you are right. The assets are get from server are with the requested headers.

I may have not been clear about my real issue.
I'm trying to make an API call to an external server with get command. and that's where I get the error:  
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.SOMEURL.com. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. Are you in control of the server at SOMEURL.com?

Comment: Sorry I completely understand your answer now.
Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm having trouble accessing the post data for XDomainRequest() requests made from IE9. I'm using `var obj = request.body;` This works fine for all post requests made via `xmlHttpRequest()` Any ideas?

Comment: ok, found the answer. `xDomainRequest` **does not send a `content-type` header** and bodyParser cannot work without it. To fix, simply add a default `content-type` header using middleware.

Comment: how do you restrict the api call to be made from one other location?

Comment: Having had the same issue as described by the question owner, I found that ONLY adding these headers in the server side wouldn't work. For some reason, by changing code in the CLIENT side and making a request to `"http://localhost/<port>"` instead of `"localhost/<port>"` made it work.

Answer (score 61):

Following @Michelle Tilley solution, apparently it didn't work for me at first. Not sure why, maybe I am using chrome and different version of node. After did some minor tweaks, it is working for me now.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

In case someone facing similar issue as mine, this might be helpful.

Comment: Notice the app.all vs app.get.
It is OPTIONS request not GET

Comment: This works for me (I'm fetching objects using Backbone). I'm trying to figure out if it will work in IE 8... seems like it should, but I don't know if anything special is required for this "XDomainRequest" thing ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Browser_compatibility

Comment: SOME INFO FOR FUTURE USERS: I am re-directing my domain name to a heroku repo which is why I was running into this issue. Anyways, the first answer worked locally but not after I pushed it to heroku. However this answer worked after pushing to heroku.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck This doesnt work for me on heroku, did you do anything else?

Comment: @BenCraig, No, but it actually stopped working for me after the first try. So I am actually still having this problem as well.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck dang. I sent in a heroku ticket, I hope they have some sort of solution

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I got mine working (it was just hrefs), by adding target="_blank"

Comment: @BenCraig, I will have to give that a try.

Answer (score 13):

Try to this [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm modules.

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

This module provides many features to fine tune cors setting such as domain whitelisting, enabling cors for specific apis etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
var app = express();

app
.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
    next();
})
.options('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.end();
})
;

h.readFiles('controllers').forEach(function(file){
  require('./controllers/' + file)(app);
})
;

app.listen(port);
console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
```

this code assumes that your controllers are located in the controllers directory. each file in this directory should be something like this:

```
module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
        res.end('hi');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) express module. This allows you to whitelist domains, allow/restrict domains specifically to routes, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

You must set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, if you want to use "cookie" via "Credentials"

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var allowedOrigins = [
  "http://localhost:4200"
];
var origin = req.headers.origin;
console.log(origin)
console.log(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1)
// Website you wish to allow to
if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
}

// res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader(
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
  "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
);

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader(
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization"
);

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
```

});

Add this code in your index.js or server.js file and change the allowed origin array according to your requirement.

Answer (score -9):

One additional step I needed to take was to switch my URL from `http://localhost` to `http://127.0.0.0`

Comment: What are you referring to?