# CORS issue with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

So I am setting up an app to allow cross domain request. Been using a variety of methods from this post [How to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in the express.js framework on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/node-js-express-cross-domain-scripting)

However I get an error I can't seem to sort out. Here's what I am using (not that I tried about 3 of the methods outlined - they all give the same error).

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
  next();
})
.options('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.end();
});
```

This gives me an error still:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/blah. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

If I comment out the top code I get the expected not allowed error which seems to indicate that the request is properly being handled by that code. I have also retyped the content-type request to ensure that I had not pasted odd characters.  Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers. The last one's going to win.

You probably want one `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header with a value that's a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cors plugin, easier like that and no need to set up the res.header manually

get plugin here: https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors

Example REST API code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    connect = require('connect'),
    app = express();

app.use(connect.bodyParser()); //For POST method JSON form data

//GET method
app.get('/books', cors(), function(req, res){
      //send JSON etc
      res.json({});
});

//POST method
app.post('/books/', cors(), function(req, res){                          
    var book = req.body;

    //insert book to DB etc

    //send result back to client
    res.send(book);
});

//start server on port 3000
if(!module.parent){
  app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port + '.');
  });
}
```

Now you can access the REST API from any location, port etc, cheers