# Enabling CORS in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I have a NodeJS server running in on machine SERVER with the IP . The NodeJS server code works. For example, I can connect using the following `telnet` command

```
telnet <ip_server> <port>
```

or via `curl`

```
curl -d "{}" "http://<ip_server>:<port>/"
```

I need to access via another machine CLIENT with the IP . However, `telnet` won't connect and `curl` returns a `connection refused` error. Only pinging the SERVER from the CLIENT works. In the long run I need to access the SERVER from Javasrcipt code loaded in CLIENT browser. When doing this in Firefox, I can see the following error message in the Developer Console

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://<ip_server>:<port>/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

For the last couple of hours I've been trying to enable CORS within the NodeJS server code. I tried various version to do this I found on the Web

```
...
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
...

var app = express();

 // Version A
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

// Version B
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});


// Version C (using the "cors" package)
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

But nothing seems to make a difference. While the `telnet` and `curl` commands work when called from the SERVER, nothing works when trying from CLIENT. What do I miss here?

(I'm aware that blocking cross-domain requests is an encouraged security mechanism. However, this is a purely experimental setup, where I need a virtual machine (CLIENT) can access my local PC (SERVER) running the NodeJS server code.)

EDIT: As request, below are imho the relevant client code snippets. I use the NodeJS code for both HTTP accesses and to connect to a WebSocket. As I mentioned, all is running well running in from the CLIENT

```
...
doAjaxRequest : function(serverUrl, method, data, callback) {    
  $.ajax({
    url: serverUrl, type: method, data: data, dataType: "json",
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){ callback(response); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ },
  });
},

updateBoundingBox : function(endpoint, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
  var url = "http://<ip_server>:<port_http>/...";
  this.doAjaxRequest(url, "post", { }, Utility.bind(this, this.onBoundingBoxUpdated));
},

...

if ("WebSocket" in window) {
  websocket = new WebSocket("ws://<ip_server>:<port_ws>/");
}
```

EDIT2: Here are the error messages I get from the different ways to access the SERVER from the CLIENT:

```
// Browser
// Connect to WebSocket
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://<ip_server>:<port_websocket>/
// HTTP Request
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://<ip_server>:<port_http>/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.


// TELNET
$ telnet <ip_server> <port_http>
Trying <ip_server>...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused


// CURL
curl -d "{}" "http://<ip_server>:<port_http>/"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip_server> port <port_http>: Connection refused


// ping <ip_server> (works fine)
```

One issue might be that CLIENT "varies". `telnet` and 'curl' I call directly from the virtual machine with a local IP (192.168.xxx.xxx). When using the browser, the CLIENT runs on the router/proxy machine with a global IP. When I try to execute `telnet' and 'curl' on the router/proxy machine, but commands just hang. They don't connect, but I don't get any connection refused error either.

Comment: Your server code seems correct, show us your client side JS.

Comment: I added some client code snippets. Apart from the JS code, `telnet` and `curl` already fails to connect.

Comment: This site might be helpful: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js + Express + Cross-domain scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/node-js-express-cross-domain-scripting)

Comment: So wait, the browser running on CLIENT gives a CORS error but telnet and curl from the CLIENT give `connection refused`?

Comment: I edited my question, adding the exact error messages. I also noticed that having this virtual machine with a local IP might be an issue; see EDIT2 as well. @aug: Yeah, I found those pages. This "CORS on ExpressJS" was essentially what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somestimes one really has to look for the simplest solutions first. After ruling (almost) anything else out, I eventually checked for any firewall issues. And indeed there is ufw installed on client. After I allowed access to the required ports, everything is working smoothly.

Thanks for all comments! They definitely kept me searching and finally looking in the right direction.