# Node Express Cross Origin for $http.get() calling

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, cross-domain

I did a simple node server , which I need it to be Cross Origin for `$http.get()` calling , so I add the required headers to the `app.use` as details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182153/831294) answer. Finally the server code is -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('.'));

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.listen(port);
console.log('server runs on port: ' + port);
```

In my `index.html` there is angular `$http.get()` calling to a another origin -

```
$http.get('http://itunes.apple.com/search', {
    term: 'johnson'
});
```

but still this calling is denied by the browser and return error -

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://itunes.apple.com/search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How could I make Cross Origin `$http.get` calling from the `index.html` correctly ?

Comment: Why do you allow CORS on your own webserver and wait it would be allowed on Apple server?

Comment: I'm new in node , please give me an solution if yoe have ..

Comment: Short answer: it is imposible to make cross-domain requests from your webpage while CORS is not allowed on the server. Since you haven't control on itunes you cannot do it

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't understand how cross-origin resource sharing works. Cross-origin requests should be allowed on server you making requests to, not on your server from which you are serving your page.

So, the answer is you can't make request to apple website if they haven't allowed you to do it.

P.S. You have allowed other websites to make request to your website by adding this code to your express app:

```
  app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
```

Comment: So how I can call to `$http.get('http://itunes.apple.com/search', {...})` and get back the response JSON ?

Comment: You cannot do this.

Comment: You can't make such request from your webpage's javascript.

Comment: And from the the node's js file it is possible ?

Comment: If you really want to solve this problem you should add function to your web server which would make a request to this page from nodejs and then call it from your webpage's javascript

Comment: You are welcome.  It' s conventional on stackoverflow to accept answers which is helpful to you ))