# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue when API call made from React (Isomorphic app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I'm running into an issue with my isomorphic JavaScript app using React and Express.

I am trying to make an HTTP request with axios.get when my component mounts

```
componentDidMount() {
  const url = 'http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/iphone/fighters/title_holders';
  axios.get(url).then( res => {
    //use res to update current state
  })
}
```

I am getting a status 200 res from the API, but I am not getting any response data and getting an error in my console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/iphone/fighters/title_holders. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However, if I make the request in my server.js

```
const url = 'http://ufc-data-api.ufc.com/api/v3/iphone/fighters/title_holders';
axios.get(url).then(res => {
    //console.log(res);
});
```

It works fine and I get response data when the server starts. Is this an issue with the actual API or am I doing something wrong? If this was a CORS issue I'm guessing the request in server.js wouldn't work either? Thanks!

Comment: If someone  has the error when testing locally  there are many answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome/45433997#45433997

Answer (score 35, accepted):

CORS is a **browser** feature. Servers need to opt into CORS to allow browsers to bypass same-origin policy. Your server would not have that same restriction and be able to make requests to any server with a public API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Create an endpoint on your server with CORS enabled that can act as a proxy for your web app.

Comment: @Todd security should always come before convenience. Luckily provisioning proxy servers can be a 5 minute exercise. Additionally there are proxy services that expose this type of functionality already but only allow so many free requests. Setting up your own proxy is worth the extremely minimal effort.

Comment: I've got the same problem and i've read the docs you have mentioned above still don't get idea of CORS can you elaborate it, please

Comment: @SagarGautam Can you make a new stackoverflow question and mention everything you're having trouble understanding, then comment here with the link to your post? I'll be happy to answer

Comment: I've asked question here please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701630/typeerror-networkerror-when-attempting-to-fetch-resource

Comment: I have the same issue.In my case I can create records from desktop computer web browser but cannot create through my iPhone web browser.

Answer (score 25):

Use the google Chrome Extension called [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en). It modifies the CORS headers on the fly in your application.

Comment: use it for testing purposes only. Your users are not going to enable plugins on their browsers to use your website

Comment: It's also available for Firefox.

Answer (score 24):

### Fix Without Using External Proxy or Chrome Extension

CORS should be enable in server side! if you can not activate it on server (for example using external API) create a middleware `React -> Middleware -> Orginal Server`.

1. Create a Node.js project (Middleware) and use below code in `app.js`.

   ```
   const express = require("express");
   var cors = require('cors')
   const app = express();
   app.use(cors());
   const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
   app.use('/api', createProxyMiddleware({ 
       target: 'http://localhost:8080/', //original url
       changeOrigin: true, 
       //secure: false,
       onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
          proxyRes.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
       }
   }));
   app.listen(5000);
   ```

This will pass the request `http://localhost:5000/api/xxx` to  original server (for example `http://localhost:8080/api/xxx`), and returns the result to client.

2. Change client (React) to call proxy and get data without CORS error (you only need to change the port in url):

   ```
   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/xxx', //proxy uri
   {
      headers: {
         authorization: ' xxxxxxxxxx' ,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      } 
   }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   });
   ```
3. run node project `node app.js` and react project `npm start`.

Comment: My app is react and js without express.. should I install express to fix the problem?

Comment: No, these are completely different beasts. You create a standalone webserver acting as a proxy between your app (different port on a localhost) and the server (different domain). `onProxyRes` simply catches the original server response and masks it so that client thinks it has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` which is not the case for a protected server.

Comment: For example, I created a new node.js app inside my project root (`/cors-proxy/index.js`) and addded (here for windows) expo launcher script: `"web": "cd cors-proxy && start cmd.exe /c node index.js && cd .. && expo start --web --port=8080"`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem. the other answers are correct but there is another solution.
you can set response header to allow cross-origin access.
according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o) you have to add the following codes before any app.get call:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
  });
```

this worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

```
        //install cors using terminal/command  
        $ npm install cors

        //If your using express in your node server just add
        var cors = require('cors');
        app.use(cors())


       //and re-run the server, your problem is rectified][1]][1]
       **If you won't be understood then see below image**
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeqmc.png

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same error today, using React with Typescript and a back-end using Java Spring boot, if you have a hand on your back-end  you can simply add a configuration file for the CORS.

For the below example I set allowed origin to * to allow all but you can be more specific and only set url like http://localhost:3000.

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
public class AppCorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with the `fetch` command. A quick look at the docs from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api) tells us this:

> If the server you are requesting from doesn't support CORS, you should get an error in the console indicating that the cross-origin request is blocked due to the CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being missing.

You can use no-cors mode to request opaque resources.

```js
fetch('https://bar.com/data.json', {
  mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
})
.then(function(response) {
  // Do something with response
});
```

Comment: However keep in mind that a response for a no-cors request has a response type of 'opaque', which means that you won't be able to read the data returned from the server

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code when using vs code on debugging mode.

> **"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security","--user-data-dir=~/ChromeUserData/"]**

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Chrome disable-web-security",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--user-data-dir=~/ChromeUserData/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Or directly run

`Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/ChromeUserData/`

Comment: Do you have idea how to make vsc use this configuration automatically when i run "npm start" ? I must use F5 to make chrome use launch.json. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer for your question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err)

> To have Chrome send Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header, just alias your localhost in your /etc/hosts file to some other domain, like:
>
> 127.0.0.1   localhost yourdomain.com

Comment: Your answer will work only if a client tries to access localhost for local development. OP asked about access to real server.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I missed reference to localhost in error message.

Answer (score 1):

Because the server don't have CORS header, so you are not allowed to get the response.

This is header from API that I captured from Chrome brower:

```
Age:28
Cache-Control:max-age=3600, public
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Fri, 06 Jan 2017 02:05:33 GMT
ETag:"18303ae5d3714f8f1fbcb2c8e6499190"
Server:Cowboy
Status:200 OK
Via:1.1 vegur, 1.1 e01a35c1b8f382e5c0a399f1741255fd.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:GH6w6y_P5ht7AqAD3SnlK39EJ0PpnignqSI3o5Fsbi9PKHEFNMA0yw==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:b971e55f-b43d-43ce-8d4f-aa9d39830629
X-Runtime:0.014042
X-Ua-Compatible:chrome=1
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
```

No CORS header in response headers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but I was getting the same error when remote debugging a react-native application. I was running the debugger on **192.168.x.x:8081**. I read a little bit on this [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/) to educate myself on what CORS is. (I'm a beginner) and changed my URL from **IP:8081** to **localhost:8081** and my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Create-React-App has a simple way to deal with this problem: add a proxy field to the package.json file as shown below

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8081",
```

Comment: and what does it mean, that 8081 port?

Comment: allow every request with this domain

Comment: this did not work for me in react and fastapi

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue occurs when you try to call an endpoint via your react app because react app is running on localhost:3000 and apis are on different servers.

to rectify this error install 'http-proxy-middleware'

```
npm i http-proxy-middleware 
or
yarn add http-proxy-middleware
```

after installation create a ***setupProxy.js*** in your ***src*** folder

and follow below code

```
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    
    module.exports = function(app) {
    
        app.use(
        '/getDetails', //this is your api
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target:'http://10.0.0.20:9000/getDetails', //this is your whole endpoint link
          changeOrigin: true,
        })
      );


    app.use(
        '/getproducts', //this is your api
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target:'http://10.0.0.20:9000/getproducts', //this is your whole endpoint link
          changeOrigin: true,
        })
      );
      
    };
```

you can add as many api as you want in app.use.
and then just normally call the api

```
axios.get('http://10.0.0.20:9680/getDetails')
```

for more details check below link
[Porxying API requests in Development in React JS](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Answer (score 1):

use below after private property in package.json.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

The Key is `proxy` and the value is your server URL

AND  other thing is Chrome does not support localhost to go through the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
[chrome isse cors](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743)

OR

If you use Express
please add routes after use cors

```
app.use(cors());  
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
```

Comment: My app is react and js without express.. should I install express to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the CORS error even after enabling it on server side. The issue was url. `localhost:4001/todos` I forgot to prepend the 'http'.

```
http://localhost:4001/todos //correct way
```

You don't have to deal with it on client side. Just need the following steps:

Step 1:

```
npm install cors
```

Step 2:

```
//express-server.js  

...
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Add proxy to package.json file and keep the remaining part of url in the fetch itself.

eg.,

In package.json file,
"proxy" : "https://www.google.com",  //add your own website link

In App.js file
const response = await fetch(./...(as per your own))

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `server.js` in your express app

```
const cors=require("cors");
 const corsOptions ={
       origin:'*', 
       credentials:true, //access-control-allow-credentials:true
        optionSuccessStatus:200,
 }

 app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

make sure to run `npm install cors`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by simply installing "cors" in my server folder. I used express to create an api and tried to send get request to the api but it did not work without "cors".

Answer (score 0):

The error message “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource” indicates that the server that the JavaScript code is making a request to did not include the proper CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers in its response.

Here is how to solve?

1. Server side(express) install.

   `npm i cors`
2. Within entry file (**app.js** or **index.js**) add following middleware

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

/*
 * cross origin resource sharing middleware
 * allow to access from different origin
 */
app.use(cors());

// api endpoint to be fetched
app.get("/api/v1/users", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({status: "Success", data: "*Put data here"});
});

module.exports = app;
```

3. On client side (react) fetching api (component App.js)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  // Get Users
  const getUsers = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3003/api/v1/users").then((response) => {
      const theUsers = response.data;
      setUsers(theUsers.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

return (
   <div>
     <h1>User List</h1>
       {users.map((user) => (
         <h3>{user.name}</h3>
        ))}
   </div>
  );
```

**NOTE:** The catch here is that, The server side is running on port 3001 and the client side is running on port 3000. So, requesting and api from client side make it a different origin, which fails.
In order to overcome this, install cors middleware on server side as it should be handeled from server side.