# React Ajax Request gives CORS error but returns the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to make a GET request, which works fine via POSTMAN, but on react seems to don't work.

For some reason, it also returns the data, in spite of the CORS error. How can it be fixed?

API payload:
[image]

index.js (Redux setup)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'

import {assumeRole} from './libs/awsLib';

import './index.css';

import reducers from './reducers';
import {LOGIN, LOGOUT} from "./actions/UsersActions";
import {api} from "./actions/api";

const history = createHistory();
const myRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, thunk, myRouterMiddleware)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

FileListReducer

```
import {GET_DOCUMENTS} from "../actions/index";

export default function(state = [], action) {
    //reducers should return a new object, never mutate the current state

    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DOCUMENTS:
            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;
}
```

FilesActions

```
import 'whatwg-fetch'
import {api} from './api';
import config from '../config.js';

export const GET_DOCUMENTS = 'GET_DOCUMENTS';

export function getDocuments() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const request = api.fetch('warpig/document/?userId='+localStorage.getItem("id")).then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_DOCUMENTS,
                payload: {data: res, success: res.status == 200}
            })
        }, (err, data) =>  {
            console.log(err, data);
        });
    }
}
```

My way to call the getDocuments()

```
...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDocuments();
    }

    getPrograms() {
        this.props.fetchPrograms();
    }
...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchPrograms, uploads3, login, assignToken, getDocuments }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps({ programs, fileUpload, auth, filesList }) {
    return { programs, fileUpload, auth, filesList };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileUpload)
```

The main question is that's working via POSTMAN, but not working when I make the HTTP GET request on my browser via React, in spite of it's returning data, so, what might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with POSTMAN and not in the browser because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).  In order to fix this, you need the server responding with data to have the "access-control-allow-origin" header contain either * or contain your website's domain name.

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap)

Comment: Yes, CORS is enforced by browsers, servers just a give advice.  Every failed CORS request actually sends the data.