# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to know how set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in axios post method at reactJS or react-native environment?
I use CORS Add-ons and it works but I want to set it in the header too, I try these ways but none of them does not work.

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
```

and

```
let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'method':'POST',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't. That header is sent by the server. Look up CORS and how you set it depends on what the backend is.

Comment: you should set it in your backend code not from ui

Comment: what you are using as a back-end ?

Comment: Yes, I use it in UI, back-end written in Php. But, what if it does not set in back-end? what can I do then?

Comment: I got my answer, Apparently, from UI we can't access to CORS unless we build our server, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable cross origin request at your server end. A snippet of how you can do it using Express would be as follows

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

This would enable all requests to support CORS. Adapt it as per your requirements.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap/60908929#60908929) link for more information if you can not change the server.