# TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cors, fetch-api

I've found a lot of question similar to my problem but I don't get solution that's why I've asked here.

I've just started learning front end development using React. I've made separate app for front end and backend running at different ports.

Backend : Laravel framework app running at `incomeexpense.stacklearning.com/`

Frontend : React app running at `localhost:3000/`

I've a form like this:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

export default class Register extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirm_password: ''
    }
}

updateInput = (event) =>{
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;

    this.setState({[name]: value});
}

handleSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://incomeexpense.stacklearning.com/api/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirm_password: this.state.confirm_password
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Origin": "localhost:3000",
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="limiter">
            <div className="container-login100">
                <div className="wrap-login100 p-l-85 p-r-85 p-t-55 p-b-55">
                    <form className="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <span className="login100-form-title p-b-32">
                            Sign Up
                        </span>
                        <span className="txt1 p-b-11">
                            Name
                        </span>
                        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" >
                            <input className="input100" type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.updateInput}/>
                            <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span className="txt1 p-b-11">
                            Email
                        </span>
                        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36">
                            <input className="input100" type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.updateInput}/>
                            <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span className="txt1 p-b-11">
                            Password
                        </span>
                        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36">
                            <input className="input100" type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.updateInput}/>
                            <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span className="txt1 p-b-11">
                            Confirm Password
                        </span>
                        <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-18">
                            <input className="input100" type="password" name="confirm_password" value={this.state.confirm_password} onChange={this.updateInput}/>
                            <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <button className="login100-form-btn">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-48 m-t-60 text-center">
                            <label>
                                Already have an account ?
                                <a className="txt3 m-l-5" href="/login">
                                    Sign In Now
                                </a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I've following routes,

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('users',array( 'middleware'=>'cors','uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@registerUser'));
Route::get('users',array( 'middleware'=>'cors','uses'=>'Auth\RegisterController@getUsers'));
```

Here is CORS middleware,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];

        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Finally here is user creating function

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}

protected function registerUser(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return response()->json($this->create($data));
}
```

When I send the post request from react app following error is shown at console

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://incomeexpense.stacklearning.com/api/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." Register.js:39 
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked:
>
> The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://incomeexpense.stacklearning.com/api/users. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I know this error is due to different domain and browser prevent resource access to different domain.

I just want to know what I need need to do at front and at back end to make things right

PS: back end code works perfectly while sending request from postman.

Answer (score 4):

**URI Schema Mismatch**

The `Origin` request header set within the `headers` interface of your fetch request contains the host: `localhost:3000`. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header that is configured within the CORS middleware contains the host: `http://localhost:3000/`. The URI scheme/host/port tuple defined must be an exact match in both the fetch request and CORS middlewares.

Change both of your URLs to `http://localhost:3000`

See: [Fetch Spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), [CORS Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) and [CORS for Developers](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/)

**Chrome Bug**

Just to note, Chrome does not support CORS Requests for `localhost`. You can find the documented Chrome bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743). There are some workarounds listed within the bug, if need.