# How to config CORs in Reactjs on Production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I have a problem when I deploy react app to Heroku:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://rs-yoga-prod.herokuapp.com/' from origin 'https://rs-react-prod.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://rs-react-prod.herokuapp.com/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I've researched and added `proxy` in `package.json` like this:

```
"proxy": {
    "dev": { "target": "http://localhost:4000"},
    "prod": { "target": "https://rs-yoga-prod.herokuapp.com" }
}
```

But it still show error, what did I'm wrong ?

```
server URL: https://rs-yoga-prod.herokuapp.com
client URL: https://rs-react-prod.herokuapp.com
```

You can access these URL for more detail, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue when API call made from React (Isomorphic app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap)

Answer (score 1):

CORS has to be handled at the backend side. Backend has to send CORS headers on the `OPTIONS` request.

Follow are the list of headers need to return by backend for enabling CORS.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET , DELETE , PUT , OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Read more about CORS from mdn - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS