# React - Secure login using a API with windows authentication

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

I've created and testing my API which responds with authorized  or not-authorized when the credentials have been typed in. I have tested this with postman and works perfectly.

The login I am trying to create is on React and is currently looking like this -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Input } from "reactstrap";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import auth from "./auth";

export class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    login = () => {
        auth.login();
    };

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/LoginTest', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: {
                "username": this.username.value,
                "password": this.username.value
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
                        <h2 id="formTitle" className="text-center">
                        Admin Panel
          </h2> 
                        <input
                            id="inputUsername"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            name="username"
                            ref={(ref) => { this.username = ref }}
                        />

                        <input
                            id="inputPassword"
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            ref={(ref) => { this.password = ref }}
                        />

                    <button
id="button"
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-block btn-success"
                    >
                        Sign-in
          </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(Login);
```

The 2 errors which I'm currently getting are -

- 415 Unsupported Media Type
  OR
  When I use mode: no-cors
- Acces to fetch at "" from origin has been blocked by the CORS policy

Any help on this would be perfect!

Comment: This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and has to be fixed at the backend or run through a [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/). Check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: did you try checking other post by searching before posting your question? Cors are a really common problem and you should find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cors+react). Some things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497848/8300513)

Comment: I have had a good look around regarding CORS but a lot of solution haven't been working. I'm just looking through these Microsoft docs now cheers

Answer (score 0):

In your fetch options, try setting:
`mode: 'cors'`

Also make sure that you `stringify()` your body data

Take a look at [this example on the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options)