# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Even by default the crossOrigin is set to anonymous, and the image stored in AWS S3 is allowed for every request from any origin, still I am getting this error while using Texture Loader.
This case doesn't appears when I hard refresh the page, but when I run it for the first time in my React Application. Can you tell me what's the exact issue with it?
Watch the actual issue I'm facing here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/14589

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue when API call made from React (Isomorphic app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap)

Comment: Watch the exact problem here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/14589