# how fix cors error on react app and coinbase connect api

Tags: reactjs, api, http, oauth-2.0, coinbase-api

I can't get authorization URL to coinbase connect OAuth2 api.

```
fetch("https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=cc460ce71913c49e4face4ac0e072c38564fabea867ebcd7ab9905970d8f3021&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=SECURE_RANDOM&scope=wallet:accounts:read")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
```

give me this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s4He.png)

Comment: try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap

Answer (score 0):

You can disable cors like that :

```
fetch('https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=cc460ce71913c49e4face4ac0e072c38564fabea867ebcd7ab9905970d8f3021&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&state=SECURE_RANDOM&scope=wallet:accounts:read', {
mode: 'no-cors',
method:'GET'
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result)
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
```