# Reactjs api call blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use mailchimp api in my reactjs application but I keep the getting the following error every time I try to call the mailchimp api.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ping' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Following is my api.js file where the mailchimp api is called:

```
mailchimp.setConfig({
    apiKey: "my_api_key",
    server: "us9"
});

const addEmailToMailchimp = async (email) => {
    const response = await mailchimp.ping.get();
    console.log(response);
};
```

It says to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the header of the request I think? Not sure how to do that. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It says to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response not the request.

I don't know how to do this in reactjs, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) might be helpful.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908929/9050888) suggests creating a midleware since you are using an external API and therefore don't have access to the server.