# How to run databricks job from react js

Tags: reactjs, databricks

[image: Error Message]I have a notebook which executes on passing inputs. We have to call the notebook in React js by getting user inputs, pass them to the notebook and execute it on clicking submit button. I have the access-token and job id with url for the connectivity credentials but I'm unable to connect. Once the job is completed, it has to notify the React form finally.

I am new to react JS. please provide me the steps how to run databricks job from react application.

I tried using below code but it is not working.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
 
    try {
 
      const vToken = 'XXXXXX';
      const vJobId = 'YYYYYY';
 
      const url = 'https://XXXXX.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now';
      const headers = {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + vToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      };
 
      const loaddate = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[-T:.]/g, '');
      const params = {
        job_id: vJobId,
        notebook_params: {
          ZZZZZZZZZ
        },
      };
 
      const response = await axios.post(url, params, { headers });
 
      if (response.data.run_id) {
        setMessage('Databricks job is running in the background');
      } else {
        setMessage('Failed to submit data');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      setMessage('Failed to submit data');
    } finally {
    }
  };
```

has context menu
Compose

Comment: It would help if you provided a snapshot of the error you were getting.

Comment: Hi Chand, I have attached error message please look into this and suggest further.

Comment: You have not posted the entire error which you are facing. but it looks like this may be a cors issue. This is the error I got when I tried to recreate the problem. There are answers in Stackoverflow which gives suggestions to address this problem. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497674/access-control-allow-origin-issue-when-api-call-made-from-react-isomorphic-ap. The suggestions point to having a proxy server and not calling the API straight from a reactjs front end. There are ways to disable it on the browser but it is unsafe to do so.