# Cross- origin request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to Upload Image in backened from frontend....I'll use ngFileUploader bower Component.
My frontend code is:

```
function SampleController(SampleData,Upload,$http) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.uploadFiles = function(files, errFiles) {
        Upload.upload({
      url: "localhost:5000/upload", //webAPI exposed to upload the file
      data: {
        file: files
      }
    }).then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp)});
    }
```

And i'll added ngf-select in its html file.
  And it will show the error-- 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5000/upload. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
  How can I resolved it??

Comment: `url: "http://localhost:5000/upload"`

Comment: The front of the URL was omitted. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: it will again give the error--  POST http://localhost:3000/upload 404 (Not Found)

Comment: So you are running at 3000 and uploading to port 5000? That is a cross domain call. You would need to add CORs header.

Comment: i have already added cors header... but it will give again the same error....

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

My project backend is laravel. So, I included this in Route file.

Comment: my backened is in expressJS. so whether i need to include these header files

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o

Answer (score 0):

Add cors filter to your application as a middleware

```
var app = require('express')();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE']);
  next();
});
```

I would recommend you white list the origins you would allow.

Comment: No.. Its not working... again give the same error of post

Comment: Confirm, your server is runing on :3000 and client on :5000? if so, the url in the client has to be http://localhost:3000/upload

Comment: if your accessing a different domain, make sure to add http:// to the url