# Receiving CORS Errors when trying to send an Angular GET Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https, get, cors

Here is my end point:

http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=#####

I get this response:

```
{"152":{"user":{"id":198,"firstname":null,"lastname":null,"username":"Lucerna-chem","email":"oliveri@lucerna-chem.ch","type":"Distributor","password_temp":null,"code":"omrotFVDQS3T75wTFUS67W0kUnXUpePrvaP5Pha9QevHjB0olSjPIxhmmJuZ","active":1,"logo_path":"lucerna-chem.jpg","created_at":"2014-10-15","updated_at":"2017-01-30","email_again":"","notification":"","send_invitation":"1","last_logged_in":null,"last_logged_out":null,"logged_in_count":"24","is_online":"0","group":"","cd_count":"10","mmd_count":"11"},"logo":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD\/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz\/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz\/wAARCABBARUDASIAAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKzt .........
```

I am trying to send an Angular GET request to that URL. 
This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
  <h1>{{myData}}</h1>

</div>

<script>

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  }

  ]);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=#####")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});


</script>
```

However, I keep on receiving CORS errors in the console.

[image]

How do I prevent CORS errors? Is there anything that I can do get my data to display?

Comment: It’s not clear how this if different from the question you asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032996/angularjs-http-cors-get-nginx. I that other question you describe how you tried to configure your nginx server to send the right headers. But if you did that and the headers are still not being sent as expected, then it must be some problem in your nginx config.

Comment: What do you usng in your backend.Generally the error comes due to  backend in which your browser doesn't support localhost request.solution for this is you need to include some of the header file.Your backend is on PHP or Laravel or what??

Comment: Yes the back end is php Laravel and Nginx.

Comment: @sideshowbarker : I'm just showing to u that I can get the data fine when I visit it directly. How comes I don't get the cors error when I visit it directly?

Comment: Why do I get error only when I used angular ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936492/cross-origin-request/41936598#41936598.
Checkout this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get error only when I used angular

You will get that error any time you make a Web application that has any client-side JavaScript that sends a cross-origin request to `http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=*****` using `XMLHttpRequest` or the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or any library that uses those (for example, jQuery).

So it’s not a problem specific to angular.

As far as why you get this error, it’s because browsers restrict your Web apps from making cross-origin requests from JavaScript—unless the site the requests are sent to opt in to allowing it.

And the way sites opt in to allowing cross-origin requests is by sending a response that includes an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that indicates which origins it allows requests from.

So a site that sends an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header is telling browsers that it allows XHR/Fetch cross-origin requests coming from any origin.

And browsers are the only tools that check for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. (And the only tools that send the `Origin` request header.)

---

Consider if you use `curl` or something to request a document from a server: The server doesn’t check the `Origin` header and refuse to send the document if the requesting origin doesn’t match the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. The server sends the response regardless.

And as far as clients go, `curl` and non-browser tools don’t have the concept of an origin to begin with and so don’t usually send any `Origin` header to begin with. (You can make `curl` send one—with any value you want—but it’s pointless because servers don’t care what the value is.)

And `curl`, etc., don’t check the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header the server sends, and refuse to get a document if the request’s `Origin` header doesn’t match the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server response. They just get the document.

But browsers are different. Browser engines are really the only clients that have the notion of an origin to begin with, and that know the actual origin a Web application’s JavaScript is running in.

And unlike `curl`, etc., browsers will not let your script get a document if the XHR or `fetch()` call requesting  it is from an origin not allowed in the server’s `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Thanks for your details answer. I have a deep understanding in this CORS now. So where do I set the configuration in my server to accept cors request ? Is it as part of a web server configs like Nginx or Apache ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

In laravel, included this in Route file.

Comment: You sure route file , not Nginx conf file ?

Comment: I havent use nginx like thing. I included it in only route file of laravel. @ihue

Comment: Can you please give an example, of including those as part of laravel route ? I am using Laravel 4. Is it compatible ?

Comment: Yes it is..just include it after <?php this in routes.php where u have defined your all controllers and there routes. @ihue

Comment: Can you please give example as part of your answer ?

Comment: Also, in order for me use those header, do I need to adjust anything in my headers ?

Comment: NO any other thing you need to do.just copy and paste that three lines. @ihue