# JW Player (api.jwplatform.com) - CORS issues

Tags: cors, jwplayer7

I am having troubles in using JW Platform services in a web app developed with Angular2.

Should I assume that JWplayer  don't properly manage CORS request on the 'api.jwplatform.com'  end point?

Here is the case. I'm sending the following request

```
Request URL:https://api.jwplatform.com/v1/channels/list/?api_format=xml&api_key=BNgTpOY5&api_nonce=33502681&api_timestamp=1487003685&types_filter=manual&api_signature=287df9d7dcefaf9bcae656c518a4cc29718bcaeb
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.68.96.40:8080
```

these are the request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,de;q=0.2,es;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.jwplatform.com
Origin:https://mydomain
Referer:https://mydomain/channels
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

were *mydomain* is of course the domain from which I am sending the request.

Below the response headers I get from the end-point:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3847
Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 13 Feb 2017 16:34:46 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:openresty
X-RateLimit-Limit:60
X-RateLimit-Remaining:58
X-RateLimit-Reset:1487003700
```

As can be seen above, there is no **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'** header in the Response and therefore the app is not allowed access the retrived data.

Note that in the browser console I can see both *Status Code:200 O*K or  the *JSON data* from the server.
Everything works behind a proxy, but this can work only in a dev env.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: CORS is a SERVER setting. Angular is not responsible for it. See https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTTP GET CORS Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048116/angular-http-get-cors-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I assume that JWplayer don't properly manage CORS request on the 'api.jwplatform.com' end point?

Yes.

So if you want to get this working, the only practical solution is to either set up a reverse proxy or to use an open reverse proxy such as https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Instead of sending your request to `https://api.jwplatform.com/v1/channels/list/?…` directly,  `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.jwplatform.com/v1/channels/list/?…` is where you send it, and that then proxies your request and responds to the browser with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and other expected CORS headers.

You can set up your own instance of CORS Anywhere in Node.js with the [cors-anywhere package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere):

```
npm install --save cors-anywhere
```