# http request cross-domain in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-domain

I need to call http request cross-domain which I can consume successfully by `$.ajax` with code below. The request bases on Basic Authentication, it works.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@/api/systems",
    //crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: true
}).done(function (result) {
    $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(result.data));
});
```

However, I can't get it to work in nodejs running in server. My code is as below:

```js
var request = require('request');
var url = "https://" + username + ":" + password + "@/api/systems";
var option = {
    url: url,
    auth: {
        user: username,
        password: password
    }
};
request(option,
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    }
);
```

It always returns `Error 401 Unauthorized`.

How can I get it in nodejs?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o

Comment: are you using basic auth ?

Comment: yes. username:password is passed in URL.

Comment: try to change "password: password" to "pass: password" in request object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the npm for "cors", use it as middleware
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: i enabled cors already but still no luck. I see that the authentication header is not sent to requested server yet. Do you have idea to fix it?