# NuxtJS $axios Send Cookies With Request

Tags: javascript, http, module, axios, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS's `$axios` module and I am interacting with a backend API that set's an authentication cookie for further authenticated requests after logging in. I've looked into `withCredentials: true`, but it is still not cooperating properly.

Do I need to set a specific header value or is something wrong with my axios configuration?

I just want to keep and use this cookie received from logging in successfully and use it in the next requests to make authenticated requests.

```
// nuxt.config.js
axios : {
    ...
    credentials: true,
    withCredentials : true,
    requestInterceptor: (config, {store}) => {
        config.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        config.headers.common['API-Key'] = 'my_api_key';
        return config
    },
    ...
},
```

and here is where I am making my axios request

```
async asyncData({ $axios}) {
    try {
        // this response sends back an authentication cookie
        const login_response = await $axios.$post("my_login_route",{
            password : this.password,
            username : this.email,
        });

        if(login_response.success){
            // how i send my cookie to this route to prove im authenticated?
            const authenticated = await $axios.$get("my_url");
            console.log(authenticated); // always false; doesn't send cookie recieved in login $post request
        }else{
            console.log("Invalid username or password");
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I've made a test page with making a simple request to check if the user is authenticated. **Turns out, the axios settings in the `nuxt.config.js` are NOT being applied here.**

I need the axios configuration to apply to not just the base URL, but to my API routes. Here is a test method that activates when I press a test button:

```
check_auth : async function(){
    try {
        const response = await this.$axios.$get("https://<my_url>/Utility/IsAuthenticated/");
        console.log("IS AUTH:");
        console.log(response.isAuthenticated);
    }catch(error){
        console.log("something went wrong.");
    }
},
```

**HTTP REQUEST HEADERS FOR AXIOS REQUEST MADE RIGHT ABOVE**
As you can see, there are no cookies or `API-Key` headers that I specified in the axios config.

```
Host: <my_url>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:1337/send/account
Origin: http://localhost:1337
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

What do I need to change in my axios `nuxt.config.js` section to allow the axios configuration to apply to my api route? Do i need to use the `proxy:{}` section?

Please help!!

Comment: So the auth token is returned as a Cookie in the cookie header?

Comment: Yes, the response from the successful Login has a set cookie header. This all works in postman

Comment: Can add more information? What is the login URL? Can you show the cookie which gets returned? Have you set the baseurl at config level?

Answer (score 2):

So the issue was **NOT** axios after all.

The API I'm connecting to does not allow outside origins to use it's cookies, some cross-origin thing. The issue was that axios was not giving any warnings about the Cross-Origin issue until I tried using `fetch()`, which is where I saw the warning in my console about the server not allowing cross-origin cookies or something, and started doing research.

Related:

[How to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in the express.js framework on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o)

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853

Thanks for the help in the comments so far, but at the looks of it, the axios library doesn't have any near fix to this as it's a widespread built-in browser security thing.

If anyone has another suggestions or answers regarding getting this to work on the **CLIENT** side in a **browser**, please share with us all.